# New to Java and having issues writing and example

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

The book I am working from is called 'Java in 2 semesters- third addition' On chapter 3 I am doing an example (number 5) which I cannot make work so my understanding and logic must be all wrong!

The question wants me to write a program to take an order for a computer system. the basic system is for example £300. The user then has to choose from two different monitors at 2 separate prices. Then the user is prompted for optional extras say a dvd at £65.99 or a printer at £125. the user needs to select from these options then the program will display the total amount of the overall order.

I have tried writing this using nested if else.. and using switch. I am having issues with the selection of the multiple items storing the calculations and the final calculation of ALL items selected.

I split the program in two using price1 then price 2 but it will not compile as i have variables that need initializing. I understand why but have no thoughts on a better solution or things to try :(

I am not looking at any giving me the answer straight away in code I want to understand the logic and program flow so I can learn from what I am clearly doing wrong!!

This is a basic example and nothing fancy as it is early in the book and has only just gone through keyboard inputs if else.. case and switch so one of these must be the solution if I can think this through correctly.

Thanks

--- Code ---

import java.util.*;

public class orderComputer
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double baseunit = 375.99;
    double screen1 = 75.99;
    double screen2 = 99.99;
    double dvd = 65.99;
    double printer = 125.0;
    int total1;
    int total2;
    double price1;
    double price2;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("************************************************************");
    System.out.println("*           This is a computer order system                *");
    System.out.println("*   You have already selected the Base Unit at £375.99     *");
    System.out.println("*               1. For the 38cm Screen                     *");
    System.out.println("*           2. For the 48cm Sceen £99.99                   *");
    System.out.println("************************************************************");
    total1 = keyboard.nextInt();

    switch (total1)
    {
        case 1: price1 = baseunit + screen1;
            System.out.println("The price is currently £" + price1);
            break;
        case 2: price1 = baseunit + screen2;
            System.out.println("The price is currently £" + price1);
            break;
        default: System.out.println("You did not select a screen!!");
    }

    System.out.println("************************************************************");
    System.out.println("*           This is a computer order system                *");
    System.out.println("*   You have already selected the Base Unit at £375.99     *");
    System.out.println("*               1. DVD at £65.99                           *");
    System.out.println("*           2. For a printer £125.00                       *");
    System.out.println("************************************************************");
    total2 = keyboard.nextInt();

    switch (total2)
    {
        case 1: price2 = total1 + dvd;
            System.out.println("The price is currently £" + price2);
            break;
        case 2: price2 = total1 + printer;
            System.out.println("The price is currently £" + price2);
            break;
        default: System.out.println("You did not select a screen!!");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please show the relevant code

Comment: why so many variables? You start with `float totalPrice = 0`, then in the if/else cases do something like `totalPrice = totalPrice + 125`

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without any code, there's nothing we can help with apart from mere guessing. In fact this is a close-reason ("Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.")

Comment: Trying to post the code as we speak. It is all over the place though with all the attempts I have tried......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the "uninitialized variables":
The simplest fix is to initialize the variables to some value of your choice, e.g.:

```
double price1 = 0.0;
double price2 = 0.0;
```

Though your code compiles just fine on my machine (java 1.8.0_91).

**But** be careful how the values are initialized/changed during program flow. E.g. and invalid input in one of the two `switch`-statements would cause your program to spit out an incorrect value.

Instead use an approach that removes redundant variables. E.g.: why use multiple variables for summing up the total price? Simply reuse a single variable for all additions:

```
double price = baseunit; //we know for sure the user selected the base-unit

...

switch(total1){
    case 1:
        price += screen1;
        break;
    ...
}

...
```

Don't create variables for single-use values. Eliminate the usage of `total1` and `total2`:

```
double baseunit = 375.99;
double screen1 = 75.99;
double screen2 = 99.99;
double dvd = 65.99;
double printer = 125.0;
double price1;
double price2;

...

switch(keyboard.nextInt()){
     ...
}

...
```

Simply continuing a program, after the user entered an invalid input won't produce any useful/correct value. Notify him about the fact that the value he entered was useless and afterwards either terminate or ask again:

```
switch(keyboard.nextInt()){
     ...

     default:
         System.out.println("Invalid input");
         return;     //invalid input was entered, program is terminated
}
```

Comment: Paul, many thanks for the the answer and helping with this. I am going to go and sort this out as you advise and hopefully then I am there with this exercise! I did try price1 = 0.0 but when the program went to the second phase it cleared the price1 value so when you selected say the printer  the over all price was only 125.0! Yes there are a lot of variables as this is how I was trying to solve this issue. Fingers crossed this will work.... Many Thanks

Comment: @grahil24 I've already pointed that out in the answer: initializing the values to some default-values only fixes the immediate problem with the compilation-error. But the problem regarding the behavior of the program won't be fixed by this. To fix this you'll have to take the other approach I've mentioned and eliminate code that produces the errors.

Comment: Thanks Paul, looking at this now :)

Answer (score -1):

Try a more object-oriented approach. You are learning OOP, aren't you? :)

Create a class for a Product item. The class will have a Description field (string) and a Price field. Create a list to represent the customer's order, and Add all of the items (basic computer, monitor, any options) that the customer selects to the list. Each line item would be one Product. Once that is done, you can get the total by iterating over the list and adding up their Price fields.

Comment: I doubt that'll help OP much in the state he's currently in. How is someone that is just learning the basics of conditional programming supposed to understand OOP?

Comment: I agree Paul but maybe the book wants me to skip forward although if it did why is the question in this chapter entitled 'selection' !! I have been trying to look at a solution from the subject matter the chapter has given...

Comment: @grahil24 I doubt the book is designed in a way to make you skip that many chapters forward. And from personal experience (both student and teacher): this question is definitely about conditional code execution, not OOP. My recommendation: stick to the structure of the book, anything else is quite likely to get you entirely confused.

Comment: Thanks Paul, great advise and the solution above is going to really help as well. I am preparing to return to uni in september and I am trying to get ahead. I dont want to skip chapters as you are right this will be very confusing. Solid and sound advice I thank you very much

Comment: Still not compiling here - intellij IDE. Must still be doing something incorrect!

Comment: correction compiling but not running. must be something with switch (keyboard.nextInt())

Comment: YEsssss its working now, the ide was having a bit of a fit too but finally sorted :)